# How to share a program use with other computers over the web?

Tags: windows-7

I have posted this question in 3 times- each place someone tells me its the wrong place to post it. Hopefully this is the right place.

I have a program that is open source on my Laptop. Since then i have added features to customize the program for online gaming. Now the program works great. My friends would like to use the program, but most of then are not techies. It took me months to update the original programs-with combination of other programs and scripts.

My question is : Is there a way to store my 'program' online inside a cloud or something that my friends can download a .exe and use the full program on their computers. I just want to upload my 'program' then have a .exe file downloadable for my friends to install the use of the 'program' from their computer. the program is not a virus nor causes any thing to go wrong with the user's computer. Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance.

The patches and scripts i added on are open source-however, there's alot to download and install if you do it from start to finish. I want a way to run the program with all associated files and script online where any one can download an .exe and run the program (entirely) on there computer. How can i do so? I like the idea of a cloud server- but how to i run the program on the cloud all the time and allow users to download a .exe file to use it? kinda like a firewall software. I say like a anti virus and firewall because i intend to update the files and scripts as time goes by. I need to know of any apps, or servers that will allow me to meet my needs. And how. I'm new to distribution of software over the web-so be king guys please. I'm not sure if i have to create a .exe file so users can download and have access to the program via the web or is there something already made that will work for me?

Comment: Please be more specific about the open source application and the changes/additions you have made. Have you changed the source code and your friends wouldn't be able to compile it? What exactly do you want to distribute? Which part of your application should run online and why? Please make sure this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: The only way you can do this is by having scripts that, upon execution, modify everything that you want. These scripts can be .bat files or .vbscript, etc. You can then use a .bat script to execute all scripts and send everything in a .zip file. The question is, do you have all these scripts somewhere?

Comment: @danzel Just to list a few programs in the directory: wireshark (color list and scripts) OPENvpn , VPNguardian (with add ons and script), Ipblocker (with a list of IP address from https://myip.ms/ and other trusted sites) I linked the list from myip.me website to a txt file where i can add to the ipBLOCKer list. PLUS i have a few more scripts all of which help with network security for online gaming. Their all work together well. INSYNC  so i want to upload all my programs and the programs i made to connect them together.  Then my friends can download a single .exe file and use it.

Comment: If the applications in said directory are self-contained (i.e. don't need to be installed) you can simply create an archive (e.g. zip) that contains the folder and send that to your friends (e.g. via a file server). Alternatively, you can write a script that automates this procedure. You could create a self extracting archive as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896241), and automatically create a desktop shortcut to your point of entry script. The only thing you can't do (AFAIK) is create a single executable that can be run on its own.

Comment: @danzel I don't understand how i can merely .zip the programs i have installed on my computer and send them to my friends. Their will have to install each program individually  and  edit each options. This took me 30 hours to do. Not to mention the updates from Microsoft distributions and drivers. There has to be a way to have them use the collective program with a platform Kinda like how a anti virus works.The anti virus connects to the server online to get updates and measures to protect the computer and network. how do i link them together? computer > internet > server> program